# GeoLocation API Calls against an EVE RESTful API

Tags: mongodb, rest, geojson, eve

I easily can store geolocation Data into MongoDB with an Eve RESTful API Server running.
So I store data like:

```
loc : {
  lng: 13.01111,
  lat: 51.01111
}
```

Validation etc. works nicely.

But: I was unable to find a way to get geolocation data out of the REST API.
There are [sample queries](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/#op._S_geoWithin) over there working fine at the command-line, but there seems to be no way to query the API a appropriate way.

1. Is there a way to throw MongoDB like Queries against the REST API or
2. which is the prefered way to customize the API for such a purpose.

To make things clear: There is already a 2d index and geoWithin queriey at the mongo-cmd are working fine.
It's just about how to query via the REST API.

Answer (score 1):

It's not mentioned but it should be supported. I'm not into geo stuff but I just tried to issue a `$near` query and it returned an operation failure because my database was missing the necessary 2dindex. This means that the command was correctly passed to the database.

If you are using a rest client like Postman the syntax should be something like this (I'm using `$near` for simplicity):

```
?where={"loc": {"$near": {"$geometry":{"type": "Point", "coordinates": [13,51]}}, "$maxDistance": 100}}
```

If you are using `app.get` method remember to `json.loads` your query. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Points in MongoDB can be stored as either GeoJSON Point Objects,

```
 loc : {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: [13.0111, 51.0111]
        };
```

or legacy coordinate pairs.

```
loc : [13.01111, 51.01111]
```

The collection should have an index (either 2dsphere or 2d, respectively) to handle queries efficiently.

I'm pretty sure EVE has a built-in geoWithin operator. It's just not working because you're querying an invalid location format.

Comment: As I mentioned queries on the command-line are working fine. But it is true, I've missed to mention, that I already created an 2d index and did some successfull geoWithin queries on the command-line. I am not sure that EVE has an geoWithin operator and it is not mentioned anywhere at the docs as far as I can see.